# How to modify table once its created in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

I m trying to modify table its give me the following error:

[image]

There is no data in this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [SSMS option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956176) that governs this behaviour:

> Tools -> Options -> Designer -> Uncheck "Prevent saving changes that
>   require table re-creation"

IMHO, It's bizarre that this option is enabled by default, even more so when the SSMS Designer uses drop and re-create for some things that do not need it (i.e. changing the nullability of a column)